# subprocess.Popen() a python file with an infinite loop never calls the file

Tags: python, subprocess

I have two .py files on a Raspberry Pi where I am trying to call one file, keep_awake.py, which contains:

```
import time
import serial
while True:
    time.sleep(5)
    for option in ["on", "off"]:
        for board in ["ACM0", "ACM1"]:
            request = serial.Serial(f"/dev/tty{board}", 19200, timeout=1)
            for j in [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,"A","B","C","D","E","F"]:
                request.write(f"relay {option} {j}\r".encode("utf-8"))
            request.close()
        time.sleep(.1)
```

This code is writing to relays to click buttons via wires soldered into the circuit boards. I have tested this code and know that it works. However, when I call it from the parent file like this
`subprocess = Popen(["python", "/home/pi/Desktop/DLMW-ART/tools/keep_awake.py"], stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT, universal_newlines=True)`
The code does not run.

The purpose of this is to push the devices button so that it stays awake during a firmware update, and then kill the subprocess so it doesn't interfere with the rest of the script. So I want the parent file to look like this:

```
#Several print statements to let me know where in the script I am
subprocess = Popen(["python", "/home/pi/Desktop/DLMW-ART/tools/keep_awake.py"], stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT, universal_newlines=True)
#Firmware update code will live here
time.sleep(20) #used for testing the call
subprocess.kill()
```

This code runs in a loop, so I can clearly see the multiple print statements in the main file, but nothing happens in the subprocess, and the devices are not clicked. Am I making the subprocess.Popen call incorrectly?

Comment: The code looks OK; I wonder if the subprocess is started, but for whatever reason never gets scheduled by the OS to actually *run*.

Comment: Might be important info, on a Raspberry Pi, editing that into the question

Comment: Yeah, maybe everything gets put on hold until the firmware update is complete, then you kill the script that never got to run.

Comment: I thought that might be the problem, so I am currently testing with just a time.sleep(20) between the popen and the kill

Comment: You're calling a board named board, not the actual boards.

Comment: @mauve are you referring to the first block of code? Because that is not where my question is. I can run that file independently of the subprocess and it works as expected.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#printf-style-string-formatting